# MSQL update script using join on multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a column in one table where the values in several other columns match the values in a separate table. I have been using this update statement in MYSQL 6.2 for MAC:

```
update vendor_import vi
join vendor v on 
vi.vendor_name = v.vendor_name
and vi.vendor_alt_name = v.vendor_alt_name 
and vi.vendor_legal_name = v.vendor_legal_name
and vi.division_name = v.division_name 
and vi.vendor_address = v.vendor_address 
set vi.contractor_id = v.contractor_id;
```

When I try to run this script in MYSQL 6.3 for Windows I am getting a syntax error.

Comment: which syntax error?

Comment: After 'vi.vendor_name = v.vendor_name' it tells me I am missing 'set'

Comment: See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql